# Sibling relation that just doesn't seem to cover all cases

Tags: prolog

I've been tasked with creating a sister relation in prolog, among other basic relations. The issue is that my assertions dont cover all angles for reasons that I just dont get. Currently I have

```
female(X)).
male(X).
parent(X,Y).

sibling(X,Y) :- female(X), parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y).

female(mom).
female(mary).

male(tim).

parent(mom,tim).
parent(mom,mary).
```

With that, my code works fine when testing it with something like sister(mary,tim) (equals true) or sister(father,tim) (equals false) but i'm currently having issues with it defining sister(mom,tim) as true. While that may very well be a true statement somewhere on this world of ours, it's not something I feel is correct given the assignment im working on.

Comment: Predicate names cannot begin with a capital letter in Prolog. Beyond that, this code is not syntactically correct and doesn't make any sense. Please copy/paste actual working code.

Comment: I'm using the SWI-Prolog program to code all of this. we're only lightly grazing logic programming to understand a few core concepts related to logic and have really only been using assertions and storing it in I guess what would be the local database of the current session. however ill try to edit it to what a more commonly seen format, my mistake lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* start your programs with things like this:

```
female(X)).
male(X).
parent(X,Y).
```

You may think that these are "declarations" of the relations you will be using, but they are not. They are *definitions* of rules saying "anyone is female", "anyone is male", and "any object whatsoever is a parent of any object whatsoever". Delete these.

Then, let's decompose your problem a bit. A sister is a female sibling. The sibling relation is useful in itself, so let's define that first without worrying about sisters in particular:

```
siblings(X, Y) :-
    parent_of(Parent, X),
    parent_of(Parent, Y).

parent_of(mom, tim).
parent_of(mom, mary).
```

Observe how I renamed your `parent` relation to `parent_of`. This is not a symmetric relation, and for a term like `parent(X, Y)` we might not know which argument is the parent and which one is the child. Naming it `parent_of` is more suggestive: `parent_of(X, Y)` means (reading left to right): `X` is the parent of `Y`.

We can now test this:

```
?- siblings(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = tim ;
X = tim,
Y = mary ;
X = mary,
Y = tim ;
X = Y, Y = mary.
```

Note that this is not correct yet! It says that Tim is his own sibling, and that Mary is her own sibling. You need to fix that. I'll keep using it for the moment.

Now, as we said, a sister is a female sibling. That's easy to express now:

```
sister_of(Sister, Sibling) :-
    female(Sister),
    siblings(Sister, Sibling).

female(mom).
female(mary).

male(tim).
```

`Sister` is the sister of some `Sibling` if `Sister` is female and they are siblings. That is all. Note that these variable names are more informative than `X` and `Y`!

Let's test:

```
?- sister_of(Sister, Sibling).
Sister = mary,
Sibling = tim ;
Sister = Sibling, Sibling = mary.
```

Only Mary is anybody's sister, which is what we want. She is also her own sister, which we do not want, but that is the same problem noted above in the definition of `siblings/2`.

Comment: I see, thank you for the thorough explanation; If i ever have to deal with prolog again after this assignment i'll definitely be better prepared now haha, cheers!